# Table of contents for externally defined (with expl3) Tcolorbox environment

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox, expl3

**See EDIT below if you are returning to this question, the question is still unanswered albeit some progress**

I am writing lecture notes for a course I'm taking. I'm trying to create a table of contents for a set of theorem environments that are not the usual ones from `tcolorbox`.

I had an annoyance before using `tcolorbox` theorems requiring two `{}{}` after the `\begin{}` part for every theorem environment defined by `newtcbtheorem` In another post I made, [a user was cleverly able to define](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581964/78181) an external `betternewtcbtheorem` using expl3 that circumvented the need for the options  and rather now, titles and labels are optional.

I have in my preamble five `betternewtcbtheorem` environments:

- Theorem
- Definition
- Corollary
- Proposition
- Lemma

Some have titles but not all, and some have labels but not all. Some are in sections within chapters and sometimes they are in chapters but not sections

**Goal:** I am trying to make it so the table of contents lists each theorem, definition, corollary, definition, lemma under each chapter or section it is held within along with the page number. I want to include the title of the object if it has one, and just the theorem number if it doesn't have a title. I also want to make the ToC clickable (preferably using the `hyperref` package so that one can navigate through easily).

**I have tried the other solutions posted online but I do not understand how to modify them in order for it to work with this external definition because they are made with the regular `theorem` environments**

An example (mimicking the code later in the post) would be like:

```
Lecture 1...              Pg#
    Theorem 1.1: Test Theorem 1...       
    Prop 1.1: Test Prop 2...        
 Section 1...              Pg#
    Theorem 1.2...            
    Lemma 1.1: Test Lemma 1...             
    Definition 1.1: Definition 1...        
Lecture 2...                           Pg#
    Theorem 2.1: Test Theorem 3     
    Corollary 2.1
```

I give a working example of the structure below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath , amsthm , amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-75pt}{\parskip}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


%This is where betternewtcbtheorem definition starts
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\betternewtcbtheorem}{O{}mmmm}
{
    \newtcbtheorem[#1]{#2inner}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{O{}}
    {
        \keys_set:nn { hushus/tcb } { ##1 }
        %Start of where I add to the table of contents
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#3: \hspace{0.4em}\l__hushus_tcb_title_tl}
        %End of where I add to table of contents
        \hushus_tcb_begin:nVV {#2inner} \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl \l__hushus_tcb_label_tl
    }
    {
    \end{#2inner}
}
\cs_if_exist:cF { c@#5} { \newcounter{#5} }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hushus_tcb_begin:nnn
{
\begin{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hushus_tcb_begin:nnn { nVV }
\keys_define:nn { hushus/tcb }
{
    title .tl_set:N = \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl,
    label .tl_set:N = \l__hushus_tcb_label_tl,
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
%This is where betternewtcbtheorem definition ends.

\betternewtcbtheorem[number within = chapter]{dfn}{Definition}%
{
    enhanced,
    before title = {\stepcounter{dfn}},
    colback=blue!10,
    colframe=blue!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=blue!35!black}
}{dfn}

\betternewtcbtheorem[number within = chapter]{thm}{Theorem}%
{
enhanced,
before title = {\stepcounter{thm}},
colback=green!10,
colframe=green!35!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
top=3mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
boxed title style = {colback=green!35!black}
}{thm}

\betternewtcbtheorem[number within = chapter]{prop}{Proposition}%
{
    enhanced,
    before title = {\stepcounter{thm}},
    colback=cyan!10,
    colframe=cyan!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=cyan!35!black}
}{prop}

\betternewtcbtheorem[number within = chapter]{lem}{Lemma}%
{
    enhanced,
    before title = {\stepcounter{thm}},
    colback=Dandelion!10,
    colframe=Dandelion!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=Dandelion!35!black}
}{lem}

\betternewtcbtheorem[number within= chapter]% init options
{crl}% name environment
{Corollary}% Title
{enhanced,
    before title = {\stepcounter{co}},
    colback=red!10,
    colframe=red!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=red!35!black}
}% options
{co}% label prefix


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Lecture 1}
    \begin{thm}[title = Test Theorem 1,label=thm1]
        abc
    \end{thm}
    \begin{prop}[title = Test Prop 2,label=prop1]
        abc
    \end{prop}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{thm}
        abc
    \end{thm}
    \begin{lem}[title = Test Lemma 1]
        abc
    \end{lem}
    \begin{dfn}[title = Definition 1]
        abc
    \end{dfn}

    \chapter{Lecture 2}
    \begin{thm}[title=Test Theorem 3]
        
    \end{thm}
    \begin{crl}
        abc
    \end{crl}

    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
I got some resemblence of what I want working as you can see, by adding to the `\newdocumentenvironment` part a `\addcontentsline` which references the environment name and its optional title. **The current issues are: Not being able to display the envionment number (like Theorem 1.1) and not including a colon if the environment does not have a title (like in the second theorem).**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: a solution would be to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thethm}#1}`. Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60872/ams-theorems-in-table-of-contents) could help you.

Comment: @sRaviolii The code you have put does not work for me and also, I have seen that post before and unfortunately I couldn't get the answers to work (or work the way I need).

Comment: in that case, I do not know how to help. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to help you with a part of your question. I don't know anything about the "betternewtcbtheorem-part", so I hope you're able to integrate that part yourself. Hopefully, the answer helps you a bit further in your search for the total final answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath , amsthm , amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-75pt}{\parskip}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

% For the preamble theorems:
% \newtcbtheorem [#1 initial options] {#2 environment name}
%                {#3 Theorem title name} {#4 options} {ref #5:##3}

% For the theorems inside your document:
% \begin {#2} [##1 extra options] {##2 Title Name} {##3 refname}
%      content
% \end{#2}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\new@tcbtheorem}[5][]{%
  % numbered theorem
  \@@newtcolorbox[#1, auto counter, number within=section, 
                list inside=theoremlist]%
            {#2}[3][]{#4, ##1%
    title={\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\thetcbcounter}{##2}},
    list entry={\protect\numberline{\yourfont#3~\thetcbcounter}##2},
    code={\tcb@theo@label{#5}{##3}}}%
  % unnumbered theorem*
  \@@newtcolorbox[#1, no counter, list inside=theoremlist]%
            {#2*}[2][]{#4, ##1,%
    title={\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\@empty}{##2}},
    list entry={\protect\numberline{\yourfont#3}##2},
   }}
\makeatother

% Then place all your theorem environments

\newtcbtheorem[]% init options
{dfn}{Definition}%
{
    enhanced,
    colback=blue!10,
    colframe=blue!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=blue!35!black}
}{dfn}

\newtcbtheorem[]% init options
{thm}{Theorem}%
{
enhanced,
colback=green!10,
colframe=green!35!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
top=3mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
boxed title style = {colback=green!35!black}
}{thm}

\newtcbtheorem[]% init options
{prop}{Proposition}%
{
    enhanced,
    colback=cyan!10,
    colframe=cyan!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=cyan!35!black}
}{prop}

\newtcbtheorem[]% init options
{lem}{Lemma}%
{
    enhanced,
    colback=Dandelion!10,
    colframe=Dandelion!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=Dandelion!35!black}
}{lem}

\newtcbtheorem[]% init options
{crl}% name environment
{Corollary}% Title
{enhanced,
    colback=red!10,
    colframe=red!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=red!35!black}
}% options
{co}% label prefix

% Then define your preferred Theorem ToC settings
\newcommand{\yourfont}{\itshape}% Theorem ToC font 

    \makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@tcolorbox{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{100pt}}% indent, numwidth
    \makeatother

% Then place the Theorem ToC in the preferred location of your document
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
% ToC Theorems as section inside your main ToC
        \tcblistof[\section*]{theoremlist}{List of Theorems}

    \chapter{Lecture 1}

    \begin{thm}[]{Test Theorem 1}{thm1}% title and ref label
        abc
    \end{thm}

Referring the Theorem number by \ref{thm:thm1}.

    \begin{prop}[]{Test Prop 2}{prop1}
        abc
    \end{prop}

    \section{Section 1}

    \begin{thm}[]{}{}
        abc
    \end{thm}

    \begin{lem}[]{Test Lemma 1}{}
        abc
    \end{lem}

    \begin{dfn}[]{Definition 1}{}
        abc
    \end{dfn}

    \chapter{Lecture 2}

    \begin{thm}[]{Test Theorem 3}{}
        
    \end{thm}

    \begin{crl}[]{}{}
        abc
    \end{crl}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, while your solution makes sense to me -- the underlying issue is that my ```betternewtcbtheorem``` was defined in a language I don't fully understand, so I don't know how to modify it to make it work this way. I also prefer not having to type ```{}{}``` everytime I start a theorem, so I want to stay with the environment I have. Hopefully someone can work of your solution and generalize it to my situation. Thanks!

Comment: I will award you the bounty for atleast providing some knowledge to modify the ToC once I get it working