# Using package showlabels with tcbtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox, labels, showlabels

I would like the use the package `showlabels` to display the labels of everything I have in my document, as https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Latex-questions/Keep_track_of_your_labels_with_showlabels demonstrates. I'm using the `newtcbtheorem`  environment to create theorem/lemma boxes, which automatically come with labels (as discussed here: [Main text of tcbtheorem environment absorbed into options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581961/main-text-of-tcbtheorem-environment-absorbed-into-options)). However

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, urlcolor = red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{showlabels}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mylemma}{Lemma}%
{colframe=blue!45!white,enlarge top by=0.15cm,before
skip=3pt,after skip=6.5pt,fonttitle=\slshape,breakable}{lem}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{thm}

\begin{document}


\[
E=mc^2 \label{eq:einstein} \tag{\ding{37}}
\]
As we can see from \eqref{eq:einstein}

\begin{mylemma}{Substitution lemma}{substitution}
Lemma in a tcolorbox
\end{mylemma}
Reference to the lemma \ref{lem:substitution}
\end{document}
```

the lemma box is not visibly labelled in the output (whereas the explicitly `\label`ed equation is):
[image]
(MWE inspired in part by [Label equation with a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/label-equation-with-a-symbol)).

Answer (score 0):

You mention that theorem/lemma boxes automatically define labels, such as `lem:substitution`.  My guess would be that that's doing it in such a way that it's using the original definition of `\label`, rather than the one that `showlabels` has altered.  I would have thought that the definition used would be the one in effect when `{mylemma}` is expanded, but I can imagine circumstances where it is instead the definition in effect when `{mylemma}` is defined.

If so, then it *might* be that this would magically work if you were to put showlabels before the package that defines `{mylemma}`.  Otherwise, it would involve stepping through what `{mylemma}` is actually doing, to see what definition of `\label` it's using.